# WorldClim data NA for my coordinates

Tags: random-forest

I am trying to run a species distribution model using random forests in R.
I have location data for species occurrence in a national park.
When I load the WorlClim data, the data for my coordinates is all NA.

Why is this?

Is it because my overall location is too small/narrow?

When I ask for random WorldClim data in my location is gives it?

```
> r <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)
> r <- r[[c(1,12)]]
> values <- extract(r,points)
> df <- cbind.data.frame(coordinates(points),values)
> head(df)
  lon       lat Temp Prec
1 xx.16025 -xx.42106   NA   NA
2 xx.15480 -xx.41602   NA   NA
3 xx.15359 -xx.18017   NA   NA
4 xx.14291 -xx.26207   NA   NA
5 xx.13306 -xx.14253   NA   NA
6 xx.12042 -xx.00593   NA   NA



> e <- extent(SpatialPoints(data))
> bg <- sampleRandom(r, 5000, ext=e)
> head(bg)
     Temp Prec
[1,]  208  460
[2,]  203  482
[3,]  198  491
[4,]  201  472
[5,]  199  473
[6,]  194  490
```

Comment: Is CRS of `points` the same one of `data`?

Comment: Maybe you swapped lat and lon?

Comment: I read somewhere that it must be lon / lat in that order, which it is for all. And yes, data is the same as points. I ran it again using the exact same name (points) for both and it's the exact same result

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227585/how-to-use-r-to-extract-data-from-worldclim looks like you need to use raster lib

Comment: I have the raster lib loaded

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem...

I set it out like this...

```
values <- extract(climatedata,points)
```

With points being my coords added to a spatial datafrmae

I needed to set it out like this...

```
values <- extract(climatedata,xy)
```

with x,y being the raw coords